# Concatenate two or more optional string in Java 8

Tags: java, string, java-8, concatenation, option-type

I have a rather simple question for you guys. In Java 8 it was introduced the `Optional` type. I have two objects of type `Optional<String>` and I want to know which is the more elegant way to concatenate them.

```
Optional<String> first = Optional.ofNullable(/* Some string */);
Optional<String> second = Optional.ofNullable(/* Some other string */);
Optional<String> result = /* Some fancy function that concats first and second */;
```

In detail, if one of the two original `Optional<String>` objects was equal to `Optional.empty()`, I want the whole concatenation to be empty too.

Please, note that I am not asking how to concatenate the evaluation of two `Optional`s in Java, but how to concatenate two `String`s that are inside some `Optional`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution I found is the following:

```
first.flatMap(s -> second.map(s1 -> s + s1));
```

which can be cleaned using a dedicated method, such the following:

```
first.flatMap(this::concat);
Optional<String> concat(String s) {
    second.map(s1 -> s + s1);
}
```

However, I think that something better can be found.

If we want to generalize to a list or an array of `Optional<String>`, then we can use something similar to the following.

```
Optional<String> result =
    Stream.of(Optional.of("value1"), Optional.<String>empty())
          .reduce(Optional.of(""), this::concat);

// Where the following method id used
Optional<String> concat(Optional<String> first, Optional<String> second) {
    return first.flatMap(s -> second.map(s1 -> s + s1));
}
```

Note that in order to compile the above code, we have to manually bind the type variable of `Optional.empty()` to `String`.

Comment: Unless you have a semigroup binary operator, flatmap is the best way to combine two options. Like in scala you could do `first |+| second`

Comment: Nope, that's the best you can do in Java 8.

Comment: So, you're saying that I cannot do better :( Can you explain the "semigroup" thing?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link.

Comment: That `s + s1` creates a new StringBuilder on every cycle, allocates a new String, then destroys the builder and any strings left from the previous cycle. Memory allocation is one of the heaviest tasks and you're doing tons of it for no reason. Plus it still doesn't fulfill the requirement you said that if any one is empty to return an empty string.

Comment: Nope, the flatMap blocks any operation in case of Optional.empty(). Moreover, eagerly optimization is a well known antipattern.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I'm fairly certain you're wrong about that. Might look into it tomorrow when I wake up. Can't do it from my tablet in bed. Also if the pattern is literally the worst way to do the task, then don't follow the pattern.

Comment: I honestly didn't expect your solution to work, but here's the problem I warned you about in this test https://pastebin.com/YtfBG0cN. For 100000 units in the stream before the first empty your solution runs 24 seconds, mine runs 60 milliseconds. Also yours would use over 100 extra MB of memory. Deride it as an "anti-pattern" all you want, but using an explicit StringBuilder is the best way to go.

Comment: Wait, but you started from the point that my solution was functionally wrong, remember? I did not deride your solution. I have only stated that you should not optimize your code if you have not any evidence that it does not fit to your problem. Cheers.

Comment: If `first` is empty and `second` is not, then first.flatMap(s -> second.map(s1 -> s + s1)) will return empty, which is incorrect. That is to say: `Optional.empty().flatMap(s -> Optional.of("second").map(s1 -> s + s1))` will return empty(), instead of `"second"`.

Comment: @CostiMuraru if first is non-empty but second is empty, the result will be empty too. So it seems to be the intended behavior that the result is only non-empty when both inputs are non-empty. At least, it’s a consistent behavior.

Answer (score 5):

You can stream the `Optional`s and reduce them with a `concat`.

```
Optional<String> first = Optional.of("foo");
Optional<String> second = Optional.of("bar");
Optional<String> result = Stream.of(first, second).flatMap(Optional::stream).reduce(String::concat);
```

If you are using Java 8 replace the `flatMap` operator with `filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get)`.

Consider also to use the `joining` collectors: this will return `String`, not an `Optional<String>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like :

```
Optional<String> result;
result = first.isPresent() && second.isPresent() ?  Optional.of(first.get() + second.get()) : Optional.empty();
```

Comment: also account for the scenario where just one is not present

Comment: @ds011591 Is does, the condition is `&&`

Comment: so if one and not the other then return nothing? Id think you'd want to return the value of whichever was present at the time.

Comment: @ds011591 Note that the question itself reads *In detail, if one of the two original Optional<String> objects was equal to Optional.empty(), I want the whole concatenation to be empty too.*

Answer (score 1):

Any solution that requires a flexible number of optional strings must explicitly use a `StringBuilder`, rather than rely on the compiler to generate one for you.

```
String concatThem(Stream<String> stringsin) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    stringsin.forEach(s -> sb.append(s));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

If you have a `Stream<Optional<String>>` then it becomes:

```
String concatThem(Stream<Optional<String>> stringsin) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    stringsin.filter(Optional::isPresent).forEach(s -> sb.append(s.get()));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Otherwise if you have N optional strings you end-up with a heavy cycle of creation and destruction of N-1 single-use StringBuilder objects (generated at compile time) and N-1 strings.

Edit: I had misread, so here's how to do it if any of them is missing to clear it all:

```
String concatThem(Stream<Optional<String>> stringsin) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        stringsin.forEach(s -> {
            if (!s.isPresent()) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            sb.append(s.get())
        });
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        sb.setLength(0);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This is of course if you insist on using the new API that's light on the syntax and heavy on the execution.

Comment: You know that your solution does not respect an important basic constraint? If any of the `String`s is empty, the result `String` should be empty too. Anyway, I think there is a more functional way to walk through.

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer. I used a more functional and idiomatical approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
@SafeVarargs
public final Optional<String> concat(Optional<String>... inputs)
{
    return Arrays.stream(inputs)
        .reduce((left, right) -> left.flatMap(leftValue -> right.map(rightValue -> leftValue + rightValue)))
        .get();
}

@Test
public void shouldReturnEmptyIfFirstItemIsEmpty()
{
    assertThat(concat(Optional.empty(), Optional.of("B")), is(Optional.empty()));
}

@Test
public void shouldReturnEmptyIfSecondItemIsEmpty()
{
    assertThat(concat(Optional.of("A"), Optional.empty()), is(Optional.empty()));
}

@Test
public void shouldConcatIfNoItemIsEmpty()
{
    assertThat(concat(Optional.of("A"), Optional.of("B")), is(Optional.of("AB")));
}
```

Here's an implementation using the reduce method on Stream.

Comment: You know that every time you use `@SafeVarargs` a kitten dies somewhere?

Comment: I updated my answer with a safer variant of your solution. Check it out.

Comment: I guess there are lots of dead kittens around as `@SafeVarargs` is also used in things like `Arrays.asList(T... a)`.   If it concerns you, you could always accept a Collection or Stream as the parameter of the method instead...

Comment: Seriously, a warning from the compiler often means a problem in the code. Java is a strongly typed programming language and you should avoid any situation in which types are not well defined. It's not me that said this thing, it's Joshua Bloch in Effective Java.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another pretty way:

```
@Value.Immutable
public abstract class Person {

    public Optional<String> firstName() {
        return Optional.of("John");
    }

    public Optional<String> lastName() {
        return Optional.of("Smith");
    }

    public Optional<String> location() {
        return Optional.of("Paris");
    }

    @Value.Lazy
    public String concat() {

        return Stream.of(firstName(), lastName(), location())
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .map(Optional::get)
                .filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank)
                .reduce((first, second) -> first + '.' + second)
                .orElse("");
    }
}
```

Note that, as mentioned in other comments, the concat() method performs string concatenations without using a StringBuilder (which might not be performant if you call the method a lot of times). To fix this, in the above example we're using Immutables' [1] **@Value.Lazy**, which makes sure the concat() method is called once and the result is cached for further calls. Works great!

[1] https://immutables.github.io

Comment: this is an nice example, but it misses an important point from the original question: `if one of the two original Optional<String> objects was equal to Optional.empty(), I want the whole concatenation to be empty too.`